# Differences between Normal and Single Expression function definitions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

Assume an Android project in which I have this XML for two buttons:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.package.package.UploadPhotoViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <com.zoosk.zoosk.ui.widgets.ProgressButton
            android:id="@+id/progressButtonChooseFromLibrary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.choosePhotoText}"
            android:onClick="@{viewModel::choosePhotoButtonClick}"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.choosePhotoVisibility}" />

        <com.zoosk.zoosk.ui.widgets.ProgressButton
            android:id="@+id/progressButtonTakePhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.takePhotoText}"
            android:onClick="@{viewModel::takePhotoButtonClick}"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.takePhotoVisibility}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And an accompanying ViewModel:

```
class UploadPhotoViewModel(resources: Resources) {
    var onChoosePhotoButtonClicked: ((View) -> Unit)? = null
    var onTakePhotoButtonClicked: ((View) -> Unit)? = null

    fun choosePhotoButtonClick(v: View) {
        onChoosePhotoButtonClicked?.invoke(v)
    }
    fun takePhotoButtonClick(v: View) = onTakePhotoButtonClicked?.invoke(v)
}
```

Noting particularly the difference between how `choosePhotoButtonClick` and `takePhotoButtonClick` are declared.

When building this project, Android's databinding will work properly for `choosePhotoButtonClick`, but throws an error with `takePhotoButtonClick`, saying that there's no method that matches the expected reference signature.  Assuming these methods are created the same way under the hood, this should not happen, alas there must be some difference.

What exactly is the difference to these two declaration syntaxes?  The [official Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) doesn't mention anything functional, only that it can serve as an additional way to declare that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use curly braces without specifying a return type, Your function is implicitly retuning `Unit` (this is Kotlin for `void`), so your method:

```
fun choosePhotoButtonClick(v: View) {
    onChoosePhotoButtonClicked?.invoke(v)
}
```

Has signature of:

```
fun choosePhotoButtonClick(v: View) : Unit
```

(IDE will hint that return type "Unit" is redundant and can be ommited).

However using equals sign to shorthand a function infers the return type of expression on right hand side, for example:

```
fun itemCount() = items.size
```

Will infer return type of `Int`, so its signature is:

```
fun itemCount() : Int
```

In your case of :

```
fun takePhotoButtonClick(v: View) = onTakePhotoButtonClicked?.invoke(v)
```

Function can either return a `null` when `onTakePhotoButtonClicked` is null or return value of that method (`Unit`), which means your `takePhotoButtonClick` signature is:

```
fun takePhotoButtonClick(v: View) : Unit?
```

**(OP) direct solution to question:**

```
fun takePhotoButtonClick(v: View) = onTakePhotoButtonClicked?.invoke(v) ?: Unit
```

Can be considered less readable than the curly brace version, but this implies a return type of Unit instead of Unit? and will be picked up correctly by databinding.

Comment: Apologies for the `onGuidelinesLinkClicked` calls, the intention was that the functions would each call their respective lambda, but you are correct in assuming that the signature was the same.

Comment: Interesting though.  I'm aware that the `Unit` type was Kotlin for `void`, but the possibility of a return type of `Unit?` had not crossed my mind.  Perhaps this can be fixed by appending `?: Unit` to the end to ensure that the return is not optional?

I'll try it regardless.

Comment: @SpyisSandvich `Unit` is used in place of `void`, but it's [actually an object](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html), so nullable type  `Unit?` is valid. Appending `?: Unit` should be a valid solution, but personally I think using braces is more readable.

Comment: Appending `?:` does work in this case.  I'm opting to use this since the whole idea is to connect an onClick entirely to the functionality passed into the ViewModel, which may or may not be present, in as few lines as necessary.  If I was to do anything else with the functionality in the ViewModel though, then I would definitely favor the curly brace version.